# mapping x,y,z Coordinates into screen coordinates or projection coordinates in Kinect to XNA

Tags: coordinates, kinect, xna-4.0

I have written a program to record the joint values of the Skeleton . . basically RightHand.joint to get the X, Y , Z coordinates from the Sensor, now i want to use these values to animate my 3D model .. somehow i have gotten the formula to convert the x,y values to the real world projection but don't understand how to do that with the Z coordinate.. Also i dont understand why we need to do the following

```
 int x = (int) Math.Floor(((float.Parse(temp[0]) * 0.5f) + 0.5f) * maxWidth);
 int y = (int) Math.Floor(((float.Parse(temp[1]) * -0.5f) + 0.5f) * maxHeight);
```

Isnt it sufficient to just multiply the x and y values by the screen width & height instead of doing *0.5f (+0.5f) . . If someone could explain it would be very helpful and also how to get the Z coordinates?

Here is the code:

```
      protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
             //// TODO: Add your update logic here
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
            {
                string line;
                Viewport view = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
                int maxWidth = view.Width;
                int maxHeight = view.Height;

                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] temp = line.Split(',');

      int x = (int)Math.Floor(((float.Parse(temp[0]) * 0.5f) + 0.5f) * maxWidth);
      int y = (int)Math.Floor(((float.Parse(temp[1]) * -0.5f) + 0.5f) * maxHeight);

       //Wrong Z - value Cal (Testing)
       int z = (int)Math.Floor(((float.Parse(temp[2])* 0.5) + 0.5f) * maxHeight);

                 motion_z.Add(new Point3D(x, y, z));

             }
         }

             ModelPosition.X = (float)(motion_z[i].X);
             ModelPosition.Y = (float)(motion_z[i].Y);
             ModelPosition.Z = (float)(motion_z[i].Z);

             i++;
          base.Update(gameTime);
       }
```

Comment: I do that with a different aproach. In XNA, i give the x,y,z value position to the model without modifications. And with the World Matrix I can zoom, move, rotate the model. (My "model" is build with cylinders and spheres)

Comment: Basically I want my model to have a movement which is more natural. For eg. a fish . . so instead of using complicated functions to do that i jsut want to record a motion and animate it

Comment: Could you anyway explain me the difference between the skeletal coordinated and depth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int x = (int)Math.Floor(((float.Parse(temp[0]) * 0.5f) + 0.5f) * maxWidth);
int y = (int)Math.Floor(((float.Parse(temp[1]) * -0.5f) + 0.5f) * maxHeight);
int z = (int)Math.Floor(((float.Parse(temp[2])/4)* 20000));

 motion_z.Add(new Point3D(x, y, z));
```

The 20000 is the value of depth distance you are defining in the vector3 camera position and it should animate properly